# Numpy - odd number operations

Tags: python, numpy

Write a program that generates a one-dimensional Numpy array consisting of integer random numbers between 1 and 100. The dimension of the array should be queried by the user. After the array is generated, calculate and print the sum of all odd numbers. Then replace all odd numbers by -1. Finally calculate and print the mean of the resulting array.

How do I operate on the even numbers without creating separate arrays and extracting them?

```
import numpy as np

e = int(input('how many dimensions'))

x = np.random.randint(1,101,(e))
print(x)

u = []
for i in x:
    if i%2 != 0:
         u.append(i)

np.even = np.array(u)
print(sum(np.even))
```

Comment: Use boolean mask indexing, like so `x[x%2 == 1]`, to get all odd elements

Answer (score 1):

For any array:

```
In [396]: x=np.arange(10)    
In [397]: x
Out[397]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

The even/odd test:

```
In [398]: x%2
Out[398]: array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], dtype=int32)
```

Selecting the even ones:

```
In [399]: even = x[x%2==0]    
In [400]: even
Out[400]: array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8])
```

Selecting the odd ones:

```
In [401]: odd = x[x%2==1]    
In [402]: odd
Out[402]: array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9])
```